# ow does one loop over an array, accessing it's items by index, in jstl (1.2)?

Tags: arrays, foreach, jstl

how does one loop over an array, accessing it's items by index, in jstl (1.2)?
I know you shouldnt mix scriptlet with jstl tags but [this](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0380__JSTL/ReferenceArraybyIndex.htm) does that and i couldnt find a better reference.

This doesnt seem to work for me:

```
<%! int[] lengths  = { 29, 8, 6, 5}; %>

    <c:forEach items = "${lengths}" var = "length">
    <th><c:out value = "${lengths[i]}"/></th>
    </c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
 <%! int[] lengths  = { 29, 8, 6, 5}; %>

    <c:forEach items = "${lengths}" var = "length" varStatus = "loop">
    <th><c:out value = "${lengths[loop.index]}"/></th>
        </c:forEach>
```

Also be careful of mixing the two as i said above. 
This code above wasnt even working at first because netbeans was thinking it was all scriptlet there being no syntax error. Once i deleted it and retyped it, it was fine.